# Getting rid of one quote at the beginning of a string

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df and in 1 of the columns (region) one of the strings is "Latin/South America

How would I get rid of the quote at the beginning? I'm not not how to get rid of just one quote.

Thanks in advance

Comment: perhaps `gsub("^\"", "", vec)` but can you show your vector please -- if you can edit your question with `dput(vec)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see this example below

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
df <- data.frame(obs = 1:2,Region = c('"Latin/South America', '"Asia/Europe'))
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(Region = str_replace_all(Region, regex('^"'), ""))

#     obs              Region
# 1   1 Latin/South America
# 2   2         Asia/Europe
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks for your help